# How to create a texture paper background using CSS without image

Tags: css, background

Is there a way to create a background using CSS without the image? with color, and texture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Dustin said, there's no "texture" CSS feature. however, if you're using CSS3, you can do some pretty cool tricks like [gradients](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/) or [shadowing](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/) to make some neat backgrounds.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no "texture". However if you find a color and could drop the texture then you can. I would just find a small image to repeat.

Comment: Repeating small images in a background will take us back to the days of Geocities and Windows 95. Modern UX is beyond that stage.